# Change root directories for two domains

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, dns

I am having two domains on my Apache Ubuntu VM:

- `www.domain01.com`
- `www.domain02.com`

My current situation:

- `www.domain01.com` is openning from the path: `/var/www/html/index.html`.
- `www.domain02.com` is openning from the same path but with added directory `/var/www/html/domain02/index.html` and we should write the domain.

What I need is that to do the following:

- Make `www.domain01.com` home directory `/var/www/html/domain01/`.
- Make `www.domain02.com` home directory `/var/www/html/domain02/`.

So that when users write any domain from them, they go directly to the right path and without appearing any sub-directories in the path.

I found people talking about `.htaccess` file but when I searched about it I found it containing nothing, it contains the following:

```
deny from all
AllowOverride None
```

Note: This file is broken intentionally, we do not want anybody to undo it in sub-directory!

What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

`.htaccess` is not required for your case. Add below `<VirtualHost>` blocks to you apache configuration (`/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`).

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain01.com
    ServerAlias www.domain01.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain01/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain02.com
    ServerAlias www.domain02.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain02/
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?domain01\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^domain01/ /domain01%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

Then inside `/domain01/.htaccess` have this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /domain01/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+domain01/(\S*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,NE,R=302]
```

Comment: I am having .htaccess file only in domain01 and domain02 folders
Not in DOCUMENT_ROOT folder, where is DOCUMENT_ROOT folder? I don't find a directory with that name,

Comment: That is fine, you will need a .htaccess in root also (a level above domain01 folder)

Comment: Do you mean that I will do .htaccess file in the root?
And update the two others into the 2 domains to have such the above instructions?

Comment: Read my answer **carefully** I have written very clearly what rule is needed in what .htaccess.

Comment: Can you please differentiate the cond and rule again
let us say that www.123.com will open on the folder /var/www/html/domain01/course/

What will be the files contain in this condition?
because using the same folder name and the domain name "domain01" is ُembarrassing

Comment: I didn't understand your comment. If you don't want solution using rewrite rule then use `VirtualHost` the way @Kannan has answered.